Fighting against unwanted symbol internment when generating foreign code
This might be an XY problem so I will describe my goal first:
I want to write a function which returns unevaluated CL code, similar to macros, except that I don't want the returned code to be executed, so something like this:
(defun remote-add (a b)
  `(+ ,a ,b))

The reason I want to do this is because I am generating a Lisp routine for another CL implementation. The problem arises when I have a package which does not exist in my current Lisp environment, but is guaranteed to exist in the remote Lisp:
(defun remote-fast-add (a b)
  `(remote-only:fast-adder ,a ,b)) ;; No package REMOTE-ONLY

The way I circumvent this right now is via writing the code in strings, and I'm not too happy about it. Something without namespaces, like Emacs Lisp, makes this much easier.
Is there any wizardry I can do to actually achieve this? As far as I can tell, a special reader macro is the only way forward.

You can create empty dummy packages and then intern symbols into them:
;;; Repeat as needed for all the packages the generated code uses
(unless (find-package :remote-only) (make-package :remote-only :use '()))

(defun remote-fast-add (a b)
  (list (intern "FAST-ADDER" :remote-only) a b))

(remote-fast-add 1 2) ; > (REMOTE-ONLY::FAST-ADDER 1 2)

or you can create the package and the needed symbols in one go with defpackage:
;;; Repeat as needed for all the packages the generated code uses
(unless (find-package :remote-only)
  (defpackage remote-only
    (:use)
    (:export fast-adder))) ; Include all needed symbols from the package here

(defun remote-fast-add (a b)
  `(remote-only:fast-adder ,a ,b))

And it's easy to make it a macro to reduce the boilerplate:
(defmacro define-foreign-package (package-name (&rest symbols))
  `(defpackage ,package-name
     (:use)
     (:export ,@symbols)))

(define-foreign-package remote-only (fast-adder))


To really make empty packages in portable code, one would need to use empty :use lists in make-package and defpackage. The list of packages to use is unspecified and in most implementations not empty.

This is the right answer.  You don't need the check around defpackage because it deals with the package already existing.  As Rainer said you probably want a (:use) clause to prevent potential clashes and/or symbols which are also present in the current package (and so won't be printed with a prefix)

@Shawn The second solution is good, and beats string manipulation. It would be ideal if it could be incorporated under a macro, but I don't see it happening without using the reader. Even a macro which would accept an alist between remote packages and symbols, and then a body using those symbols, would be wonderful.

@daedsidog It's trivial to wrap it in a macro. See edit.

@Shawn What you did is indeed trivial, but what I had in my mind was something that I could use "lexically" in a single form, like: (with-foreign-symbols ((remote (fast-addr))) '(remote:fast-addr 1 2)), which I don't see it working without a reader macro. The current solution mandates splitting the form into two.

Ah, yeah I don't think a form like that is possible. But what's wrong with splitting it up? Presumably you're outputting multiple functions with these symbols; don't want to wrap each one. Too much duplication.

@Shawn Nothing is wrong with splitting it up. Neither is there anything wrong in writing the source in string form. I asked the question to expand the understanding of expressiveness in CL.
Forgive me if I am "moving the goalposts" with the question. This to me is the correct answer and I will probably inevitably choose it as such, but I really feel like CL's package mechanism should not be an obstacle to something that is done rather trivially in Schemes or even Emacs Lisp, and project my dissatisfaction at you in the form of incessant comment-complaints!

@daedsidog "Neither is there anything wrong in writing the source in string form." <-- Except that it is defying one of the few things where Lisp(s) shine over Python & co.  You can't not to intern a symbol somewhere. Typically, in situation like yours in EmacsLisp, you would generate a new symbol with the desired name in some "let" form that wraps your code generator, and than emit that symbol in your code generator. Look-up for example 'dotimes' macro in elisp for en example of the idiom. In CL you can programmatically generate and delete a package so you don't the elisp let-idiom.

Experimental code follows...
Here is a sketch for a CLOS based approach:

I'm assuming that the code will be printed on the local system and read back on the remote system

define a class with slots NAME and PACKAGE

define a PRINT-OBJECT method to write it similar to a symbol


Example:
CL-USER 9 > (defclass remote-symbol ()
              ((name :initarg :name)
               (package :initarg :package)))
#<STANDARD-CLASS REMOTE-SYMBOL 80100A447B>

CL-USER 10 > (list (make-instance 'remote-symbol
                     :name "FAST-ADDER"
                     :package "REMOTE-ONLY")
                   1 2)
(#<REMOTE-SYMBOL 801005971B> 1 2)

CL-USER 11 > (defmethod print-object ((remote-symbol remote-symbol) stream)
               (format stream "~a::~a"
                       (slot-value remote-symbol 'package)
                       (slot-value remote-symbol 'name)))
#<STANDARD-METHOD PRINT-OBJECT NIL (REMOTE-SYMBOL T) 801005E66B>

CL-USER 12 > (list (make-instance 'remote-symbol
                     :name "FAST-ADDER" :package "REMOTE-ONLY")
                   1 2)
(REMOTE-ONLY::FAST-ADDER 1 2)

Possible extensions:

smaller function / notation to create such "symbols"
provide an option to mark "exported symbols"


I suppose this would work, but it would require a very lengthy "preamble" of defining all the symbols being used in the remote program, making it seem unappealing compared to using just strings.

You can avoid using any package on the sender side if you rely on uninterned symbols and circular-detection during pretty-printing. Let's first write a macro that will help you write your functions:
(defmacro with-foreign-symbol ((name package &key as) &body body)
  (check-type name symbol)
  (check-type package string)
  `(let* ((,name (make-symbol ,(string name)))
          (,as (cons ,name ,package)))
     ,@body))

This binds name to an uninterned symbol, as well as a secondary variable, a marker that contain additional information about the symbol, here the package, but in practice maybe you need to send also information about the case (uppercase, etc.) of your environment.
Let's use it to define remote-fun, which rely on two remote symbols:
(defun remote-fun (a b c)
  (with-foreign-symbol (fast-adder "remote-only" :as m1)
    (with-foreign-symbol (fast-mult "remote-only" :as m2)
    `(with-symbols (,m1 ,m2)
       (,fast-adder ,a (,fast-mult ,b ,c))))))

Calling the function (remote-fun 5 6 7) with *print-circle* bound to T, I obtain:
(WITH-SYMBOLS
 ((#1=#:FAST-ADDER . #2="remote-only") (#3=#:FAST-MULT . #2#))
 (#1# 5 (#3# 6 7)))

The expression being built is wrapped in a  with-symbols form, which the receiving end must interpret correctly. One possible way is to define it as a macro, but if you deserialize from a socket you can just pattern match the term manually. Here I'm defining a macro:
(defun resolve (ref)
  (destructuring-bind (name . package) ref
    ;; in practice, do look up for the right symbol
    ;; ie. (find-symbol (string name) package)
    (declare (ignore package))
    (cons name (intern (string name) "KEYWORD"))))

(defmacro with-symbols (bindings expr)
  (sublis (mapcar #'resolve bindings) expr))

With this in place, you can simulate an exchange with a foreign interpreter by going through a string representation:
(macroexpand
 (read-from-string
  (with-output-to-string (o)
    (write (remote-fun 5 6 7) :stream o :circle t))))

(:FAST-ADDER 5 (:FAST-MULT 6 7))
T

We can see that the symbols where replaced by the actual symbols (here, keywords).
A benefit of this approach is that you only need to manipulate uninterned symbols and strings, and that it can be adapted to attach more information to the code you emit.
That being said, having a package that lists all the known foreign symbols is useful too, maybe its simpler.

A variant of Shawn's answer which solves the 'what symbols are there' problem is to use a function in the target implementation which simply writes a source file with suitable defpackage forms which the source implementation can then load.
Here is that function (you will need collecting):
(defun write-shim-package-forms (packages file &key (nicknames t))
  "Write a source file containing simplified DEFPACKAGE forms for a
number of packages.  This will enable another Lisp implementation to
load it at which point the external symbols in the equivalent packges
will be available to it."
  (with-standard-io-syntax
    (with-open-file (to file :direction ':output :if-exists ':supersede)
      (format to ";;;; Shim packages~%;;;~2%(IN-PACKAGE \"CL-USER\")~%")
      (dolist (p packages file)
        (let ((pkg (find-package p)))
          (cond
           (pkg
            (pprint `(defpackage ,(package-name pkg)
                       ,@(if nicknames
                             `((:nicknames ,@(package-nicknames pkg)))
                           '())
                       (:use)
                       (:export ,@(collecting
                                    (do-external-symbols (s pkg)
                                      (collect (symbol-name s))))))
                    to)
            (terpri to))
           (t
            (with-simple-restart (continue "ignore non-package")
              (error "no package ~A" p)))))))))

With this definition, then if I say (write-shim-package-forms '(:org.tfeb.hax.collecting) "/tmp/pkg.lisp"), I get
;;;; Shim packages
;;;

(IN-PACKAGE "CL-USER")

(DEFPACKAGE "ORG.TFEB.HAX.COLLECTING"
            (:NICKNAMES)
            (:USE)
            (:EXPORT
             "WITH-ACCUMULATORS"
             "MAKE-COLLECTOR"
             "COLLECTING"
             "NCONC-COLLECTORS"
             "COLLECTING-VALUES"
             "COLLECTOR-CONTENTS"
             "NCONC-COLLECTOR-ONTO"
             "COLLECT-INTO"
             "WITH-COLLECTORS"
             "COLLECT"))

This file can then simply be loaded by any CL and will define suitable packages.
